# list-item opacity 0.7 except for active items

Tags: jquery, opacity

I changed the list-items with an opacity of 0.7 what works fine.In the same list i have a list-item with the class and id "active".

The meaning is that the opacity of the active list-item is 1 but that won't work.

This is the jQuery:

```
            $("#active").css({ opacity: 1 });
            $(".nav_top ul li a").css({ opacity: 0.7 });

            $(".nav_top ul li a").hover(function()
            {
                $(this).animate({ opacity: 1 });
            },
            function()
            {
                $(this).animate({ opacity: 0.7 });
            });
```

This is the list:

```
<div class="nav_top">
    <ul>
<li class="active"><a href="#">item 1</li>
<li><a href="#">item 2</li>
<li><a href="#">item 3</li>
<li><a href="#">item 4</li>
<li><a href="#">item 4</li>
```

Comment: "Accept"? Perhaps you mean "Except" (as in excludes; doesn't pertain to)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Global "all are 0.7 opacity" rule
// exclude the li with the active class though [:not(.active)]
$(".nav_top ul li:not(.active) a")
  // change items to 0.7 opacity
  .css({ opacity: 0.7 })
  // and bind to hover
  .hover(function(){
      $(this).animate({ opacity: 1 });
  },function(){
      $(this).animate({ opacity: 0.7 });
  });
```

A couple of things though:

1. Make sure to close your anchor (`<a></a>`) tags)
2. You can use `:not()` to exclude the `active` class `<li>`

Demo found here: http://jsfiddle.net/xJF7X/2/

Comment: Ok thanks that works fine. One little question, now while I hover, the active item the opacity change from 1 to 0.7 but I don't want to change that so it has to stay 1.

Comment: Just changed your code to: $(".nav_top ul li:not(.active) a") Now the active part don't change

Comment: @LeonvanderVeen: Yes, just the selector needs to be changed. I've updated my answer to a brief/concise solution to fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this all with CSS and a little jQuery

```
<div class="nav_top">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and use these cross browser opacity styles:

```
.nav_top li {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    -moz-opacity: 0.7;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.7;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.nav_top li.active {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    -moz-opacity: 1.0;
    -khtml-opacity: 1.0;
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

and some jQuery

```
// hover on the li, not the a, since the li has the class
$(".nav_top ul li").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({ opacity: 1 });
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({ opacity: 0.7 });
});
```

Comment: Ok thanks that works fine. One little question, now while I hover, the active item the opacity change from 1 to 0.7 but I don't want to change that so it has to stay 1.